# Como exibir uma imagem específica?

Tags: php, imagem

Estou fazendo um sistema de filmes que se cadastra o pôster do filme e quero que quando gerar o relatório com todos os filmes cadastrados, ele me mostre a imagem do pôster salvo no banco e não o nome da imagem. Achei um código que mostra todas as imagens em uma tabela do banco, porém mostra todas uma em baixo da outra e no relatório quero que mostre separados, do lado do nome, como por exemplo:

Título..................Diretor...................Pôster

13: O jogador.....Gela Babluani.......Imagem

O código que eu achei na internet e estou me baseando nele é o seguinte:

```
<?php

include ('config.php');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmes ORDER BY nome_filme");

while ($filmes = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {

echo "<img src='fotos/".$filmes->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";

?>
```

Nome da tabela no banco: filmes
Nome da variável da imagem do pôster: $foto
Nome da variável do nome do filme: $nome_filme

Comment: Hmm ,você pode fazer dentro desse while, uma tabela, onde mostrará os resultados corretamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria dessa forma:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filmes ORDER BY nome_filme");

    echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>COD</td>
            <td>Título</td>
            <td>Diretor</td>
            <td>Imagem</td>
        </tr>
    ";
    while ($filmes = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$filmes['id']."</td>
            <td>".$filmes['titulo']."</td>
            <td>".$filmes['diretor']."</td>
            <td><img src='fotos/".$filmes['foto']."'></td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: deu erro em uma linha: 

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arquivos\3 bimestre\Trabalho\cadastro_filmeslst.php on line 221

Linha 221: <td>".$filmes['id']."</td>

Comment: Sim, você precisa ajustar os campos né...

Comment: Alterei, tente novamente.